# Finding all complex solutions for $z^3+i+1=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How would i go about solving this?

The equation is as in the title:

$z^3+i+1=0$

Comment: hint: rewrite as $z^{3} = -i -1$. do you know how to take complex roots?

Comment: Solving $z^n=a$ in the complexes can be done using the polar representations of complex numbers.

Comment: $z = (-1 - i)^{1/3}$. Of course, that's not the best answer you can give. What theorems of complex analysis do you know?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Do you know about polar form of writing complex numbers?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203770/how-to-find-all-values-of-z-such-that-z3-8i?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$z^3 = -1-i = \sqrt2\left(-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}-i\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right) = \sqrt2\left[\cos\left(\dfrac{5\pi}4+2n\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{5\pi}4+2n\pi\right)\right]$

Can you use De Moivre's theorem and proceed?

Comment: Thank you, this should work!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the first solution is given by $$z_1=1/2\,{2}^{2/3}-i/2{2}^{2/3}$$ then you can divide your equation by $$z-z_1$$